# Give a function $\beta$ such that $\beta \circ f$ where $f$ is the Dirichlet function gives the characteristic function of the rationals

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have brainstorming for hours to come up with a piecewise function $\beta$ such that when composed with the Dirichlet function, it gives the characteristic functions for the rationals.

Can anyone help me with this? More importantly, I am interested in the motivation in coming up with the function.

so $\beta \circ f$= $x_\mathbb Q$

Comment: Dirichlet had a lot of functions. Might help if you told us which one you mean. Also, what do you mean by "a piecewise function"?

Comment: The Dirichlet function that first cmoes to mind _is_ the indicator function (or "characteristic function", if you like that term) of the rationals.  So $\beta$ should just be the identity function.

Comment: By the Dirichlet function, I meant the function $f(x)= 0$ when $x$ is irrational and $1/q$ when $x$ is rational in its lowest term. The $x_{\mathbb Q}$ function referred to the characteristic function of the rationals. Does that clear up the confusion? Also, by piecewise continuous, it is a function that has finitely many points of discontinuity.

Comment: So, when you write, "piecewise", what you mean is "piecewise continuous"? I suggest you edit your question to incorporate the information you have put in the comments --- people shouldn't have to wade through the comments to see it.

Answer (score 1):

With the definition given in the comments, $f(x)\gt0$ if and only if $x$ is rational. So the function $\beta$ given by $\beta(x)=0$ if $x\le0$, $\beta(x)=1$ if $x\gt0$, will have the required property, $\beta(f(x))$ is $1$ on the rationals, $0$ on the irrationals. And clearly $\beta$ is piecewise continuous.